# How to install Ubuntu to a partitioned DOS disk

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, partitioning

I have just bought a new laptop running Free-DOS OS, 4 GB RAM and 1 TB HDD and want to install Ubuntu on it. I have a bootable USB from which I can run Ubuntu 14.04 in "Try Ubuntu mode". I now want to install Ubuntu on the HDD, but I noticed that it is already partitioned (2 DOS partitions). During the install, I want Ubuntu to use the entire 1 TB of disk (as treat it as 1 disk). Please can you guide me on how to "remove" the DOS partitions during/before the install?

NOTE: there is no other OS running on the laptop - I want to use it exclusively for Ubuntu.

Apologize if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

By choosing to use the entire hard drive, any existing data will be lost.  It doesn't appear as though that is a problem, but the disclaimer needs to be made.

During the installation, Ubuntu will ask you how you would like to handle the step.  If you choose, Use Entire disk and Set up LVM, you'll be removing any existing partitions and create the new Ubuntu partitions using the entire disk.

This image detects that there is no other OS installed, but even if it does the screen is similar.

[image]

Comment: Brian, your suggestion worked! Thanks again, appreciate your very prompt  response :).

Comment: Glad it worked, if you don't mind, select this as a correct answer.